# JavaScript Tic Tac Toe - Append Value into Board Stored as Nested Array

Tags: javascript

I have a function that changes the content of the board cell clicked into an X or an O, depending on the count.

Here it is:

```
let count = 0
function clickToInput(event){
    let i = event.target;
    event.target.parentElement.innerHTML = playerCounter();
    count++;
}
```

Where the function playerCounter() is defined as:

```
function playerCounter(){
        if(count%2 == 0){
            inputCharacter = "<button>X</button>";
        }
        else{
            inputCharacter = "<button>O</button>";
        }
        return inputCharacter
}
```

And here is how my board array is stored:

```
row1 = ["<button>1a</button>", "<button>1b</button>", "<button>1c</button>"];
row2 = ["<button>2a</button>", "<button>2b</button>", "<button>2c</button>"];
row3 = ["<button>3a</button>", "<button>3b</button>", "<button>3c</button>"];
board = [row1, row2, row3];
let count = 0;
```

Now what I'm trying to do is take inputCharacter and replace the string value in the nested array(which corresponds to the button that was clicked.

I didn't include my HTML as I thought it would be lengthy, but please do mention if it's necessary.

Comment: You could give the button elements their own `ids` - for example, the button on the top most left could have an id of `button_1_1`. If you have buttons with ids in the pattern - `button_${rowindex}_${columnIndex}`, then you can parse and extract the index of the button in the array from the `event.target` element's id attribute and use it to update the correct element in the array.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you create a function which toggles a Boolean X for true O for false true of false indicating who's turn it is. passing the id of the button clicked to the function. Each button getting an id.

```
var whosTurn = true;
        function turn(id) {
          var element = document.getElementById(id);
          if (whosTurn) {
            element.innerHTML = "X";
          } else {
            element.innerHTML = "O";
          }
          element.disabled = true;
          whosTurn = !whosTurn;
    }
```